# React HoC For Collapsible Panel?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

In my react app, there's a repeated UI pattern of using a collapsible panel (like an according), where there are several panels/boxes with a title bar. Clicking on the title bar expands/collapses the panel's contents.

Is a Higher Order Components method suitable for such a use case? Something like a `withAccordion(Component)`?